# Symfony3.4 - collection reference same entity field lose linked association

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

Sorry about the title, it's quite hard to describe it with just a few words. Here's the problem:

I have a customer entity which has a OneToMany with Website and customerTrackingIds :

```
class Customer {

    ...

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @Serializer\Exclude()
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\WebSite", mappedBy="customer",cascade={"persist","remove"},orphanRemoval=true)
    */
    private $webSites;


    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @Serializer\Exclude()
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CustomerTrackingId", mappedBy="customer",cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    private $customerTrackingIds;
    ...
}
```

And Website:

```
class WebSite {

   /**
    * @var Customer
    * @Serializer\MaxDepth(1)
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="webSites")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
    */
    private $customer;   


    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @Serializer\Exclude()
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CustomerTrackingId", mappedBy="website")
     */
    private $customerTrackingIds;
}
```

Customer has multiple website and multiple trackingIds. Each tracking ID is associated with one of the customer's website, but more trackingIds can exist for the same Website.

I use https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony-collection to handle the collection of website/trackingIds in the same page but when i go edit the information something really weird (at least for me) happens.

Looking in my debugger session i saw that when the form loads data from submit in my controller:

```
$formCustomer = $this->createForm( CustomerFormType::class, $customer );
    $formCustomer->handleRequest( $request );

    if ( $formCustomer->isSubmitted() && $formCustomer->isValid() ) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist( $customer );
        $em->flush();
```

When the request is handled all of the elements of TrackingIds has their website correctly set, but inside the website the customer link gets lost (becomes null). 
What happens next is that when all the data get persisted i lost in my database the phisical association between website <-> customer (customer becomes null)

How can i fix this?

Comment: How are websites set in customer entity ? did you declare add/remove methods and if so can you post the code here ?

Comment: I found the issue myself, im going to answer my own question. I feel so dumb :(

Comment: thats not dumb...

Comment: @YoannMir Thank you for your time/attention anyways. Wish u a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will ever land here i solved the issue simply double-checking my website collection form type.

Since using https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony-collection i created a new FormTheme to render the collection add/delete stuff in my page with just one field for the website collection which was the website **name**.

Anyways, inside my website collection formType i had TWO fields, **name** AND, guess what, **CUSTOMER**.

Since the FormTheme was rendering just the name field, the other one becomes null automatically, so when it was handled by the controller he was actually doing that right.